# NPM install cannot find package.json

Tags: node.js, json, github, npm, github-actions

I configured a workflow on Github and while running `npm install` it gives this error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/project/project/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/project/project/package.json'
npm WARN restaurateur No description
npm WARN restaurateur No repository field.
npm WARN restaurateur No README data
npm WARN restaurateur No license field.
```

As I understand this error implies that the `npm install` command cannot find the `package.json` file, however, I checked and `package.json` is visible in my project.

How can I solve this problem?

This is the .yml file I created

```
name: project-folder

on:
  push:
    paths: project-folder**
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    paths: project-folder/**
    branches: [main]
  
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x, 15.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: Run the tests
      run: npm test

    - name: Build
      run: npm run build
```

Comment: make sure your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are both committed and pushed to your repository.

Comment: They are both pushed to the repository.

Comment: Is the package.json file on the root repository? (similar issue: https://github.com/Azure/actions/issues/47)

Otherwise, I believe this npm install action might help you: https://github.com/bahmutov/npm-install

Comment: You could also run a step with the ls -la command just to make sure you are in the desired folder.

Answer (score -3):

run npm init command to create package.json